# How to transfer uploaded image to a directory as well as copy it to another directory

Tags: php, filepath

on my project folder there is images/committee/images.jpg . This where the uploaded images are moving to

```
if(move_uploaded_file($image_temp,"images/committee/".$new_image_name))
```

Now what m trying to achieve is that.. On the Project folder there is a folder names as

`user/images/committee/target.jpg` this where i want to copy the image to.

```
copy("images/committee/".$new_image_name, "user/images/committee/".$new_image_name);
```

i tried using this.. but i think m giving wrong path. can some one help

Comment: if you use `absolute` paths you should be OK. ie: `copy( __DIR__ . "/images/committee/".$new_image_name, __DIR__ . "/user/images/committee/".$new_image_name );`

Comment: @RamRaider it worked nicely.. actually i was applying code to the user directory thats why it wasent working. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

if you use absolute paths you should be OK. ie: `copy( __DIR__ . "/images/committee/".$new_image_name, __DIR__ . "/user/images/committee/".$new_image_name );` 
This worked for me. Do remember to check if you are in right directory if it is not working.